# flutter HERE Maps SDK - dependency on ffi: 1.0.0 - conflicting with another plugin

Tags: flutter, dart, here-api

running into the following issue where Here SDK is conflicting with another plugin (file_picker)...

> Because every version of here_sdk from path depends on ffi 1.0.0 and file_picker >=4.0.0 depends on ffi ^1.1.2, here_sdk from path is incompatible with file_picker >=4.0.0.
> So, because AppName depends on both file_picker 4.1.3 and here_sdk from path, version solving failed.
> pub get failed (1; So, because AppName depends on both file_picker 4.1.3 and here_sdk from path, version solving failed.)

The issue is the "ffi: 1.0.0" in Here's pubspec.yaml which locks in version 1.0.  For reference, I am using 4.8.3 of the SDK.  Is there any reason why Here doesn't use the carat ^ notation so that pub can use the latest 1.x version and not the hardcoded 1.0.0 version?  I can go in and change the pubspec.yaml version myself for Here SDK, but i don't want to introduce any incompatibility.  Technically this should be ok because of semantic-versions, but of course i don't want to make any assumptions.

thoughts?  thanks!

Comment: Your assumption seems to be correct, the HERE SDK officially relies on a specific Dart FFI version, which will then lead to incompatibilities with other plugins that use a different FFI version. This is a common FFI problem. If you use the carat notation it may work accidentally, but it bears a high risk. Therefore it's better to stay with what is guaranteed to work, which is in this case only FFI 1. Eventually, the HERE SDK team will update the FFI version for newer releases.

Comment: thanks Datasun, I agree it's better to be safe than lucky.  there may have been a very specific reason they didn't use the carat notation (i just wish they documented it).  i hope they update soon.  as flutter's own file picker plugin (image_picker) doesnt support images and video in the same interface which i believe file_picker does.

Answer (score 0):

We are evaluating upgrading ffi version but there is no certain timeline on this by when this will be available. It is possible to change the ffi version in the pubspec.yml but as explained above that it is risky.